# merging geometry (Feature Collections from Earth Engine) and Fusion table data for Supervised classification

Tags: google-earth-engine, google

I have data for a crop in fusion table( I had in excel format hence I converted to fusion table to use in Earth Engine). I also have feature collections (land cover classes like urban, plantation etc) obtained from earth engine platform digitization. 
Now I need to merge the crop data and other land cover data for classification for giving training set  While I try to do classification, it is showing error :
**Dictionary (Error)
Property 'lulc' of feature '2_2_0' is missing.**
Please Give suggestions

Comment: Have you checked that the property "lulc" is present in all features, as the error message suggests?

Comment: yes.. I solved the problem. I had to add a class number to the fusion table. It then stopped showing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an excel containing the lat longitude of the lulc plots. once you are done view in fusion table and then directly import your fusion table

Answer (score 0):

yes.. I solved the problem. I had to add a class number to the fusion table. It then stopped showing the error